# Find a value based on 2 criteria

Tags: excel, vba, function

I need to find a value based on 2 criteria, only that the location of that value changes.

I have the following code:

```
Function montomensual(clave As Integer, mes As String) As Double

Dim cell As Range

Set claves = Worksheets("Agotamiento").Range("C15:C500")

Select Case mes

    Case "Enero"
        For Each cell In claves
            If clave = cell.Value Then
                montomensual = cell.Offset(0, 12).Value
            End If
        Next cell

    Case "Febrero"
        For Each cell In claves
            If clave = cell.Value Then
                montomensual = cell.Offset(0, 16).Value
            End If
        Next cell

    Case "Marzo"
        For Each cell In claves
            If clave = cell.Value Then
                montomensual = cell.Offset(0, 20).Value
            End If 
        Next cell

End Select
End Function
```

However the Function returns #Value!

I do not know what I am missing, all help is appreciated.

Comment: Are there any errors in the worksheet Agotamiento?

Comment: Best practice is to use `Option Explicit` to enforce variable declaration. `claves` is undeclared. Also -- your code seems to constantly be changing its mind about the value of `montomensual`. Perhaps you want an `End Function` after the assignments?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and how exactly you are calling that function?

Comment: I think I found the problem, an example of `clave` is 060 345 3515 00 01, how would I declare that if not with Inetger?

Comment: I think you miss basic understanding of data types. Integer can take values between –32.768 and 32.767. 060 345 3515 00 01 is in the first place a string, not an integer at all. You have to convert it first and you can't convert it into an integer

Comment: @Storax that was it, still pretty new at this so thanks for the help